# ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Feature does not contain a definition for Remove

Tags: servicestack

I have referenced ServiceStack.dll ver-3.9.4

Included the code in AppHost.cs

SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{

EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Html),

});

I get the error below and cannot compile

'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Feature' does not contain a definition for 'Remove' and no extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of type 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Feature' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tried including many directives and still I cannot get past this

using Funq;

using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;

using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;

using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support;

using ServiceStack.Common.Support;

using ServiceStack.Common.Extensions;

using ServiceStack.Common.Utils;

using ServiceStack.Common.Web;

using ServiceStack.Logging.Support.Logging;

using ServiceStack.CacheAccess;

using ServiceStack.CacheAccess.Providers;

using ServiceStack.OrmLite;

using ServiceStack.WebHost;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enum.Remove](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/EnumExtensions.cs#L92) is an extension method in `ServiceStack.Common`.

You should consider using ReSharper which eliminates this issue as it auto resolves namespace references.